# Filestream on PowerBuilder

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, blob, powerbuilder, sqlfilestream

I am storing some (blob) images on a SQL 2012 express using filestream. 
I want to know how to show and retrieve those images on my client app from the database using PowerBuilder 12.5

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the PB help file:

```
Blob Emp_id_pic

SELECTBLOB Emp_pic        
INTO :Emp_id_pic         
FROM Employee        
WHERE Employee.Emp_Num = 100        
USING Emp_tran ;

p_1.SetPicture(Emp_id_pic)
```

Comment: I cant retrieve the image like that, not using filestream (already tried) any other suggestion?
Thanks anyways!

Comment: Maybe i am doing wrong the insert with filestream?

This is my insert statment

'INSERT INTO dbo.IMG_PRUEBA
VALUES(newid(), 'img1', CAST ( 'C:\Users\x\Desktop\Chrysanthemum.jpg' AS VARBINARY(MAX)))'

Comment: Matt is on the right track. There is no concept of a filestream in PB. To deal with blobs on the database, you need to use SELECTBLOB, INSERTBLOB and UPDATEBLOB.

Comment: Your initial post indicated you were retrieving images from a database, hence the SELECTBLOB answer.  If you are looking to read an image file into PowerBuilder and then save it to the DB you should take a look at FILEOPEN and FILEREADEX in the help (make sure you open the file using StreamMode!).